# Project Euler #8 - C++ code failed to work

Tags: c++

I know there are multiple topic regarding Project Euler #8.   But I am using a different approach, no STL.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

char str[] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int size = strlen(str);
    int number = 1;
    int max = 0;
    int product = 0;
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i <= size/5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = lowerBound; j <= upperBound; j++)
        {
            number = number * str[j];
        }
        product = number;
        number = 1;
        lowerBound += 5; 
        upperBound += 5;
        if (product > max)
        {
            max = product;
        }

    }

    cout << "the largest product: " << max << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the answer is : 550386080, which is way too big and incorrect.

Please tell me what's wrong with my code.  No advanced pointers or template technique, just control flow statement and some basic stuff.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: @MitchWheat it did run, just the result is incorrect.

Comment: @vincentChen that's what a debugger is for..

Comment: I suspect you need to set number to 1 between your i and j loop.  Number will keep increasing for each time through j loop since it is not reset to 1 before the j loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is the expression

```
number = number * str[j];
```

The `str[j]` is an *ASCII character* and you are incorrectly assuming it's a numeric value in the range 0..9. A cheap way to convert a single numeric character to a number would be to say

```
number = number * (str[j] - '0');
```

That gets you closer to the correct answer but there is another problem. You are testing each index range like [0..4], [5..9], [10..14], [15..19], etc. You should instead be testing indices [0..4], [1..5], [2..6], [3..7], etc. I'll leave that for you to correct.

Comment: wow! my understanding is wrong the entire time, thanks for clearing it up!
(unfortunately I can upvote you)